# SSIS Packages rename

Tags: sql-server, github, ssis, source-control-explorer

We upgraded an existing SSIS Solution from 2012 to 2016 by using the upgrade wizard.
We use TFS with GIT for source control.
After upgrading the packages we need to touch base all the packages
on -changing a connection manager 
    removing the file system task
and few other changes. there are around 135 packages.

After upgrading the packages we started making changes for them and saving them 
after modifying a 3-4 packages and saving them,
we are noticing most of them are getting renamed automatically.
We see them renamed in source control (edit ,rename)old name and new name.
I am not sure about this behavior. This happens automatically after saving the packages with changes.
anyone has any idea about this behavior

thank you

Comment: Are the old packages also in the same project still?

Comment: we backed them up into separate folder in the same project while upgrading

Comment: can you give an example of an initial name and what it become after saving?

Comment: package11,package12,package13,package14 after modifying package13  renames to package 11